# Strong connection between CoreData Entity and a View

Tags: ios, core-data, model-view-controller, architecture

How would you recommend to store data from CoreData in memory when we have such structure:

CoreData Tables/Entities -> Model Class -> UIView.

Do I really need Model Class with the same number of fields like in CoreData Entities (NSManagedObject)?

Should I store Entity.ObjectID in my views?

How would I make a strong connection between CoreData Entity and a view? Let's say in my code there is an array of entities, where each entity is shown in its own view. If I update data in a view, I need to update only specific instance of CoreData Entity.

Can't figure out what is the best approach to handle this.

Thank you!

Comment: You can achieve this using [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). Please take a look at this library. may this help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I really need Model Class with the same number of fields like in CoreData Entities (NSManagedObject)?

This is usually how it's done. Automatic subclass generation is built in to Xcode. If you don't like Xcode's classes there's [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator), a highly regarded long running open source project that provides an alternative approach.

Comment: So, you're saying that for each NSManagedObject I need to create MyEntity and copy values back and forth?

Comment: No, I’m saying that usually you’d create a subclass of NSManagedObject and use that subclass. It’s almost never a good idea to create a duplicate entity and copy values back and forth.